# "postgres" user/role does not exit upon installation of Postgres via Homebrew

Tags: postgresql, role

I am new to Postgres and I have been following instructions from this site (https://www.codementor.io/@engineerapart/getting-started-with-postgresql-on-mac-osx-are8jcopb) in order to create a local server with DB for testing.

However, once I run these commands:

```
brew services start postgresql
psql postgres
\du
```

I do not see "postgres" user (or role). (I created "newuser" by myself.) I have read that this role should be created automatically.

[image: mac terminal screenshot of roles]

I wonder, does this create some limitations? Is something wrong? Should I just not worry about it and add a role by myself?

PS: I use MacBook Air with M1 with OS Ventura 13.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the orange "Current user"?  It looks like that got created instead of postgres.  Is it really orange?  Is it really "Current user"?

Comment: No, the orange is just my name. I covered it with an orange rectangle with the placeholder "Current user" to cover my full name. It is just the result of "whoami" command when typed into the MasOS terminal to be precise. This is created by default.